# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer from only the current diagram

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, mysql-workbench

I want to create a test database from a huge schema in MySQL, but when I try to do Forward Engineer from a Diagram with about 6 tables, it try to create all the tables, views and routines groups that I have in the schema.

Is there an automatic way to do that instead of selecting one by one the tables I want?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way other than using the filter settings. Add a feature request at http:/bugs.mysql.com for a way to select only the current diagram for sync/forward eng.